# Where could I find a list weak nouns in modern English which were strong in old English?

Tags: english, nouns, old-english

So I have been doing a thing recently for which I need to find a list of all (or at least most) of weak (regular) modern English nouns (and verbs, if possible) which were strong (irregular) in old English, like boc --> bec in old English, but book --> books in modern English, and others like it, but I have so far been unable to find any such list, so if anyone knows of one, I would be very grateful for it to be able to see it, thank you.

Comment: Given how rare strong nouns are in Modern English, you could probably just get a list of all strong nouns in OE (if you can find one) and manually remove the few that are still strong noun. Not so easy with verbs, of course.

Answer (score 5):

For the Old English nouns the division into “weak” and “strong” is less important than the division into stem types. Nouns like *boc --> bec* are called “root-stems” or “consonant stems” since their stems ended in consonants, these are “strong”, here's a list: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Old_English_consonant_stem_nouns.

As for verbs, [Old English strong verbs](http://www.csun.edu/%7Esk36711/WWW/KAG/ch17.html) were regular, there were 7 [classes of strong verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Old_English_verbs#Strong_verbs), each class with its own series of vowel gradation (ablaut), about 800 strong verbs, here's a list: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Old_English_strong_verbs.

[Truly irregular](http://www.csun.edu/%7Esk36711/WWW/KAG/ch9.html) were the [suppletive anomalous verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Old_English_verbs#Anomalous_verbs) *bēon/wesan* (to be), *gān* (to go), *dōn* (to do) and *willan* (“will” meaning “to want”).

And finaly, there were [preterite-present verbs](http://www.csun.edu/%7Esk36711/WWW/KAG/ch18.html), 12 of them, lacking full paradigms and thus “defective”:

> agan = to possess (owe/ought)
>  cunnan = to know (can)
>  dugan = to achieve
>  durran = to dare
>  magan = to be able to (may/might)
>  motan = to be allowed to (must)
>  munan = to remember
>  nugan = to suffice
>  sculan = must, to be obligated (shall/should)
>  unnan = to grant
>  þurfan = to need
>  witan = to know

Now you can go through these lists and find out which ones became regular in Modern English.

Comment: Þank ðee very much, I will be sure to check ðem out.